# When do I need an impressum?

Tags: internet

I have found this statement [here](https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/7816-impressum-what-is-it-and-when-is-it-needed).

> "The Impressum is legally required on all commercial websites
> published in German-speaking countries"

What does this mean? If I publish a website, then it is automatically available worldwide ofc, so does every site e.g. a site from Nigeria also need an impressum, because it is in the world wide web and germany/austria etc. can also access it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23307/to-whom-does-the-german-impressumspflicht-apply ?

Answer (score 2):

This is for websites that operate out of a German speaking country (Germany, Austria, Switzerland) or jurisdiction - even if the website is not '.de' - OR foreign companies that direct business to Germany, or gain German customers or clients.

For example - a site from Nigeria that sold things to or had business activity with German clients would need an impressum - but not if it were a Nigerian travel blog that did not sell or had business interactions with a German jurisdiction - for example. If you do need an impressum you ALSO need an impressum on your [Social Media presences](https://www.rockit-internet.de/en/what-is-an-impressum/) (Facebook etc)

> Generally, the country-of-origin-principle according to § 3 Abs. 1 TMG
> applies, meaning that foreign organisations are not subject to the
> imprint requirement. However, many organisations do not know that a
> business location in Germany (a desk in a co-working space is already
> sufficient) leads to an imprint obligation. The same applies if the
> foreign organisation directly addresses the German market with its
> website, i.e. actively is acquiring customers in Germany. In this
> case, the organisation concerned must make an imprint available,
> because the German consumers have – according to a judgement of the
> regional court Frankfurt a.M. (Judgement of 28.03.2003, Az. 3-12 O
> 151/02) – an interest to know which law the foreign organisation is
> subject to, who exactly is the contact person and which agency
> relationships exist. - see [here](https://www.privacycompany.eu/blogpost-en/the-imprint-requirement-a-must-have-for-companies-from-outside-germany)

Other sources:
https://www.rockit-internet.de/en/what-is-an-impressum/
https://www.ionos.co.uk/digitalguide/websites/digital-law/a-case-for-thinking-global-germanys-impressum-laws/